# Derive a non linear function between two points

Tags: graphing-functions, nonlinear-system

I have to figure out a non linear function for these two data sets. The only input values i have is Start Y, End Y, Start X and End X

Here is both the functions in geogebra.

[Function1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I02Im.png) StartX = 1, StartY = 1000, EndX = 200, EndY = 100000

[Function2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W83QU.png) StartX = 1, StartY = 500, EndX = 200, EndY = 50000

[Text Version](https://pastebin.com/YRsQ6s79)

Comment: It is written below each curve, no?

Comment: Yes but it has "magic" variables like 2.5 etc which will change based on the data set

Comment: If the data set changes so will the curve. Are you leaving out information? You claim in the question that you only know two (x, y) values but your geogebra files have several data values. Are you asking 2 questions (one for each graph) or are they related in some way?

Comment: They are related as i belive their functions should be the same, They have different input variables (startX, startY, endX, endY), but the function should be the same. I am not certain about this we are making this for a fan page of a game and trying to figure out how that game calculates the values

Comment: You have y = 200 and y = 500 when x = 1 so I cannot make sense of "their functions should be the same". What do you mean by startX, startY, endX, endY here? Where are those numbers for each graph?

Comment: For dataset1 StartX = 1, StartY = 1000, EndX = 200 and EndY = 100000
For dataset2 StartX = 1, StartY = 500, EndX = 200 and EndY = 50000 first and last row of each dataset.
So based on X input i want Y output
It is an interpolation function just not linear

Comment: How did the numbers in-between come about? Sorry about the questions, but I suspect your real issue isn't really about these two data sets as such.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102660/discussion-between-swiftprog-and-paul).

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem here, more can be seen in the discussion of the first thread but I had my variables wrong